# Bring Your Own Device - Zebra Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

if anyone could help me solve this, I would be very grateful. It's for extra credit and I'm not good at all with puzzles. I've left a link to the puzzle below.

Link: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/bring-your-own-device/

Comment: Isn't this cheating?

Answer (score 1):

This is Einstein's riddle. I'd bet, it's even by same principle, just some words are mixed. Follow Einstein's and you'll have answer.